# Understanding swift Alamofire completionHandler

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have these two methods in my API class to get data from an API:

```
func authenticateUser(completionHandler: (responseObject: String?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
        makeAuthenticateUserCall(completionHandler)
    }

    func makeAuthenticateUserCall(completionHandler: (responseObject: String?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
        Alamofire.request(.GET, loginUrlString)
            .authenticate(user: "a", password: "b")
            .responseString { request, response, responseString, responseError in
                completionHandler(responseObject: responseString as String!, error: responseError)
        }
    }
```

Then in another class i use the following code to access the data:

```
API().authenticateUser{ (responseObject, error) in
    println(responseObject)
}
```

The code is working but i don't understand it completely.

1. func authenticateUser has the parameter completionHandler: (responseObject: String?, error: NSError?) -> (), is this a reference to the completionHandler method? or is it an object? whats the purpose of -> ()?
2. When i call the authenticateUser func, how do i actually access the response? There is no return in any of my api funcs,  the funcname{(parameter, parameter) in .. } syntax seems really strange.

Comment: Your edit makes the question completely incomprehensible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`completionHandler` is a closure parameter. As Swift documentation says:

> Closures are self-contained blocks of functionality that can be passed around and used in your code. Closures in Swift are similar to blocks in C and Objective-C and to lambdas in other programming languages.

So, what a closure is used for is to add some functionality of your own that you want to add to the execution of your function.

In your case, you call `authenticateUser` and you pass a closure that receives `(responseObject, error)` and executes `println(responseObject)`. `authenticateUser()` receives your closure under the `completionHandler` parameter and it then calls `makeAuthenticateUserCall()` passing your `completionHandler` closure to it.

Then again, looking at the definition you can see `func makeAuthenticateUserCall(completionHandler: (responseObject: String?, error: NSError?) -> ())` that means that like `authenticateUser()` `makeAuthenticateUserCall()` is a function that receives a closure as a parameter, under the name of `completionHandler`. `makeAuthenticateUserCall()` makes a network request using **AlamoFire** and you capture the response under a closure again that you pass as parameter of the `responseString()` method. So you have:

```
//here you call authenticateUser with a closure that prints responseObject
API().authenticateUser{ (responseObject, error) in
    println(responseObject)
}
```

Then:

```
//authenticateUser receives your closure as a parameter
func authenticateUser(completionHandler: (responseObject: String?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
    //it passes your closure to makeAuthenticateUserCall
    makeAuthenticateUserCall(completionHandler)
}

//makeAuthenticateUserCall receives your closure
func makeAuthenticateUserCall(completionHandler: (responseObject: String?, 
error: NSError?) -> ()) {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, loginUrlString)
        .authenticate(user: "a", password: "b")
        //here you pass a new closure to the responseString method
        .responseString { request, response, responseString, responseError in
            //in this closure body you call your completionHandler closure with the 
            //parameters passed by responseString and your code gets executed 
            //(that in your case just prints the responseObject)
            completionHandler(responseObject: responseString as String!, error: responseError)
    }
}
```

For more information read the documentation: [Swift Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)