# Display data from alamofire 3 + swiftyjson

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm new in Swift and iOS-dev. I'm trying to create simple app working with JSON API.

I can get and print JSON data in console:

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
         .responseData { response in
             print(response.request)
             print(response.response)
             print(response.result)
             self.output = response.response // don't work, return nil
          }
```

How can I display response with UITextView or UITableView? I just don't understand how to access data in closure..

**Update**

Looks like I miss something fundamental..:
[Why it's return nil?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRoUq.png)

Comment: use `response.result.value` to access data

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I still can't access data from outside the closure. I updated my post following your example

Comment: you should use `completionHandler` for that. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32380590/3734028). It may help you!