# ios - How to wait api response using Alamofire

Tags: ios, alamofire, swift4

I want to ask about `Semaphore` in `Alamofire`.
I want the app wait for data from the server return success and continue to execute the code after (synchronous type). I use `semaphore`, but when the api function is called, the app is suspended...

This code is call data from server:

```
func getAllModels() -> [String] {
    var _modelList:[String] = []
    let url = BASE_URL + "getAllProductAndModelv2"

    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    Alamofire.request(url, method:.get, parameters: [:], encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
        let data = NSData(contentsOf: URL(string: url)!)
        do {
            if let data = data, let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data) as? [String: Any], let models = json["models"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                for model in models {
                    if let name = model["name"] as? String {
                        _modelList.append(name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch {
            print("error")
        }
        semaphore.signal()
    }
    semaphore.wait()
    return _modelList
}
```

And this code is going to get the result:

```
let api = RestApiManager()
var result:[String] = api.getAllModels()
print(result)
```

How to relsove this issuse?
Thank you

Comment: use a closure instead, you are calling an async network method

Comment: use completion closure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32371792/understanding-swift-alamofire-completionhandler

Comment: Why dont you use serial queues?

Comment: what do you mean your app is suspended?

Comment: Unless you are experienced, which doesn't seem to be the case, do not use semaphore (it's advanced coding imho), and avoid transforming async to sync, instead understand how it works and how work with it. Also, you are Using Alamofire, then NSData contentOfUrl inside it while you should already have the data ready, that's doing twice the call, and Alamofire should already deserialize for you the JSON. Else, the app is suspended because you are blocking the current thread (main) while waiting for the reponse (twice).

Answer (score 1):

Use completion

```
 func getAllModels( completion: @escaping ([String] ,Bool) -> Void) {

    var modelList:[String] = []

    let url = BASE_URL + "getAllProductAndModelv2"

    Alamofire.request(url, method:.get, parameters: [:], encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
        let data = NSData(contentsOf: URL(string: url)!)
        do {
            if let data = data, let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data) as? [String: Any], let models = json["models"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                for model in models {
                if let name = model["name"] as? String {
                    modelList.append(name)
                }
            }

                completion(modelList,true)
            }
        }catch {
            print("error")
             completion([],false)
        }

    }

}
```

Then call it

```
 self.getAllModels { (data, success) in

        if(success)
        {
            // use data

        }
    }
```